# Best Approach to audit changes in the table

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server

I'm designing a **.NET** application where user can copy, edit, update or delete a record from a `DataGrid` element that is getting data from a table.

In the design I need to be able to maintain the versions to check all the changes that were made to the table by users. Can someone suggest what would be the best way to implement this requirement.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: This is NOT a small topic to say the least. If you don't need to have the actual user information then Change Data Capture is a pretty simple solution. If you need user information this is a big piece of work involving triggers on all the tables you need to track.

Comment: There are a number of different approaches to this depending on the specific needs of this audit log.  For example... Does the application need to be aware of the audit history?  Does the user need to be aware of it?  Does the audit history need to include more values than are in the table itself?  Does this audit trail need to happen at the table level or at the business object level?  And so on.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you are talking about a database table, then it's the best practice to actually never delete data from it. You should set a `flag` column in the table which denotes the operation performed in the corresponding row.

You can set it to `0` for active rows, `1` if the row is deleted. So, basically, you will perform an `Update` operation while deleting a row. Same can be followed for other `CRUD` operations.

Comment: That is a soft delete and by itself does not provide the tracking that the OP is looking for. You would need to add some additional auditing columns if you use this approach. I personally despise soft deletes and it clogs up the table with data that shouldn't be there and causes many bugs due to missing where predicates.

Comment: If you want to maintain history only, this approach works well enough. Adding other columns depends on the other requirements which can't be derived from existing columns. The DB architectures I have worked in, it works fine; even with a large number of records.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that you quickly violate primary key constraints.  You would need to change your unique indexes to include this active flag, and then you are still only limited to 2 versions of a given row.  This then requires that you create a composite key which alters the semantics of all crud operations and indexing strategies.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by Sean Lange, this is a complex topic and there is no silver bullet.

[Change Data Capture](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522489(v=sql.105).aspx) is designed explicitly for this problem.

If you don't want to enable CDC, then triggers are *usually* your best bet.

Here is an example of an auditing trigger utilizing [rowversion\timestamp](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776.aspx):

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table1](
    [Id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Data] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Version] [timestamp] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Table1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table1_History](
    [Id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Data] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Version] [binary](8) NOT NULL,
    [ModDate] [datetimeoffset](7) NOT NULL,
    [ModUser] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Operation] CHAR(1) NOT NULL
    ) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[trgTable1_History] 
   ON  [dbo].[Table1]
   AFTER INSERT,DELETE,UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @now DATETIMEOFFSET(7) = SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()
    INSERT INTO dbo.Table1_History
    (Id, Data, Version, ModDate, ModUser, Operation)
    SELECT Id, Data, Version, @now, SYSTEM_USER, 'I' from inserted 

    INSERT INTO dbo.Table1_History
    (Id, Data, Version, ModDate, ModUser, Operation)
    SELECT Id, Data, Version, @now, SYSTEM_USER, 'D' from deleted 

END
```

The **timestamp** column will automatically update upon every change to the row.

This provides you current + history in your audit table(which simplifies reporting). The Version column gives you an easy lookup between Table1 and Table1_History, in the event that you want to know the exact audit details of the current row.  **Updates** are designated by a DELETE(**D**) and INSERT(**I**) occurring simultaneously in the audit.